# The NaN values in data frame cannot be replaced by another data frame values by either df.update() or df.fillna()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I am trying to do is to replace the values of `df['ME']` column by the `act['ME']` column, with `df` size 10000 rows × 4 columns and `act` size 40000 rows × 1 column respectively. For both data frames, the time is used as the index. An example of df and act is shown as follows.

```
df =
                    x       y          
Time             
2020-01-01 01:00    115.1   20.0      
2020-01-01 01:01    115.0   20.1       
2020-01-01 01:02    114.9   19.9        
2020-01-01 01:03    123.1   20.0        
2020-01-01 01:04    115.0   18.9 

act =
                    ME                
Time 
2020-01-01 00:59    Sport    
2020-01-01 01:00    Home
2020-01-01 01:01    Food
2020-01-01 01:02    School
2020-01-01 01:03    Food
2020-01-01 01:04    Movie
2020-01-01 01:05    Sport
```

My expected results:

```
 df=
                       x       y      ME     
   Time             
   2020-01-01 01:00    115.1   20.0   Home   
   2020-01-01 01:01    115.0   20.1   Food    
   2020-01-01 01:02    114.9   19.9   School    
   2020-01-01 01:03    123.1   20.0   Food     
   2020-01-01 01:04    115.0   18.9   Movie
```

To get the expected results, I added a `'ME'` column to `df` by

```
df['ME']=np.nan
```

Then, I have tried 2 functions, either

```
df['ME'] = act['ME'].fillna(df['ME'])
```

or

```
df.update(act)
```

However, `df` does not update the `'ME'` column, which is shown as follows.

```
     df=
  Time                x       y        ME
  2020-01-01 01:00    115.1   20.0     NaN
  2020-01-01 01:01    115.0   20.1     NaN
  2020-01-01 01:02    114.9   19.9     NaN
  2020-01-01 01:03    123.1   20.0     NaN
  2020-01-01 01:04    115.0   18.9     NaN
```

I am not sure why the `'ME'` cannot be replaced as I have tried using `df.update()` before and no problem has exceeded.

Comment: Use `df = df.join(act)`

Comment: @jezrael Problem solved. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can simply do it with

```
df['ME'] = act.ME
```

Comment: This is not working for my code, still showing NaN. Thx!

Comment: Just don't put NANs in the df. directly copy the 'ME' column into df. @ahsojai

Comment: Still not working for me. But the function df = df.join(act) has solved my problem. Thx for your help!